# eregi_replace to preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to fix deprecated function eregi_replace() with preg_replace().

```
$text = eregi_replace('(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_+.~#?&//=]+)', '<a target="_blank" class="clickable" href="\1">\1</a>', $text);

$text = eregi_replace('([[:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_+.~#?&//=]+)', '\1<a target="_blank" class="clickable" href="http://\2">\2</a>', $text);
```

How could I get these to work with preg_replace()? I am way over my head here.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626079/convert-eregi-replace-to-preg-replace-in-php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818262/converting-an-eregi-replace-to-a-preg-replace

Answer (score 0):

You just change the name of the function and wrap your expression in a delimiter.  For case-insensitive functions `eregi()` and `eregi_replace()`, you put an `i` modifier after the last delimiter:

```
ereg('...', foo) // preg_match('/.../', foo)
eregi('...', foo) // preg_match('/.../i', foo)
ereg_replace('...', foo) // preg_replace('/.../', foo)
eregi_replace('...', foo) // preg_replace('/.../i', foo)
```

I've used the `/` delimiter here, but you'll need to use whatever delimiter makes the most sense and doesn't appear in your expression itself.

The vast majority of (if not all) common expressions will be direct carry overs, with no conversion needed.  I've converted several large projects and never run into a case where I had to actually modify the expression, but that's not to say there aren't some differences.